# Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, $f(x)>0$, and $\lim_{\|x\| \to \infty} f(x) = 0$. Show that $f$ attains a maximum.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

> Suppose that $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, $f(x)>0$, and $\lim_{\|x\| \to \infty} f(x) = 0$. Show that $f$ attains a maximum.

I am curious on how to prove this. This is what I have so far, can any one confirm that I am on the right track or offer suggestions?

Let $M > 0$ be the maximum of $f$, since $\lim_{\|x\| \to \infty} f(x) = 0$ there exists an $r>0$ such that $\|x\| > r$, this implies that $f(x) < {M\over 2}$. $B(0,r)$ is compact and therefore there exists $x \in B(0,r) $ such that the restriction of $f$ to $B(0,r)$ $g(x)$ is also the maximum of $f$.

Comment: I suppose you cannot start with letting $M > 0$ be the maximum of $f$. This is the conclusion.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I am not sure how to proceed

Comment: You just need to start with some $x_0$ such that $f(x_0) >0$. Then choose $r$ large enough so that $f(x) \le {1 \over 2} f(x_0)$ for all $\|x\| >r$. Since $\overline{B}(0,r)$ is compact, you know $f$ attains a maximum there, and hence this is the maximum of $f$ everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick $R > 0$ such that 
$$\|x\| > R \implies \vert f(x) \vert < f(0).$$
We do this to only impose an upper bound on the tail.

Since $f$ is a continuous function, $f$ attains a maximum on $\bar{B}(0,R)$, there exists $x_0 \in \bar{B}(0,R)$ such that
$$\|x\| \leq R \implies \vert f(x) \vert \leq f(x_0).$$

In particular, since $0 \in \bar{B}(0,R)$, we have
$$f(0) \leq f(x_0)$$
and therefore
$$\|x\| > R \implies \vert f(x) \vert < f(0) \leq f(x_0).$$
Combining the two cases, we have
$$f(x) \leq f(x_0) \text{ for all } x \in \mathbb{R}^n.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Choose $R>0$ such that $|x|> R \implies f(x) < f(0).$ What can you say about $f$ on $\{|x|\le R\}?$